# chrome extension get value from popup.html and using it in all active tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys I have a small problem and I need help, I creating chrome extension

**The question is that:** How can I get value from **popup.html** and using it in all tabs?

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "ext name",
  "version": "0.1",
  "author" : "myname",
  "description": "my ext",
  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches" : [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js" : ["jquery/jQuery.min.js"]

    }

  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery/jQuery.min.js","background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action" : {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

and this is my html file

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>jQuery/JavaScript</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sen&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery/jQuery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/stylesheet.css">
  </head>
  <body class="bg-dark">

<table><tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Value to get? <input class="textBox" type="text" title="get this value" id="NumberOfTabs" maxlength="1" placeholder="0" /></td>
    <td><button id="UseGotValue" class="btn btn-openTab">use this value in all acive tabs</button></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my popup.js

popup.js

```
function OpenTabs() {
 console.log( $('input.textBox').val())
}
document.getElementById('UseGotValue').addEventListener('click', function(){OpenTabs();});
```

**I want when I click button in my extension to take value of text box and using it in all tabs ?**

look to screenshot
*this is the console of my html of my extension*

https://prnt.sc/rhrhad

*and this is the console of another tabs that I opend*

https://prnt.sc/rhrhug

in other tabs I can not execute the value that I gave in my html extension

can you guys help me please?

Comment: You might want to explain what does not word in your code.

Comment: if you looking at to my popup.js code, this code only will work on my webpage of the extension, but I want to use that value in my all tabs not only in my webpage of extension, You got my point?

Comment: I still trying to find solution for this issue until now =|

Comment: You've now deleted all of your `RichTextBox` questions? Why not fix the first one and get an answer?

Comment: @Enigmativity I planing to create it again and explain it in perfect way

Comment: Sometimes I do not know to explain my ideas and what I want to people.

Comment: @Abu.Rajih22 - Think of asking in a way that gives us the steps to replicate the issue you're facing. I think I know what you're doing wrong, but until I can run your code I cannot be sure of the answer. Almost 100% of my answers I test before uploading, so the easier you make that job for me the better too.

Comment: @Enigmativity, Noted brother I will give full describe for my issue and I hope you can help me to find answer. right now I can not create new question because of policy of this site. and I appreciate that you trying to help me.